How to run 2 files at the same time with Python
I have a project I have coded with Python but the code is in 2 separate py files. When run ogether, they build up the whole app. How do I do this?
I have heard of multi-threading but I am not enirely sure how to go about it.

are the files supposed to run sequentially or simultaneously? do they depend on values in the other or do they also work standalone?

Since you are not experienced in threads / concurrent processes, I am guessing that you have split the code between two files and you want to use the code in one file from within another. If so you can simply import one file into the main program file. See link. But if you do want to run code concurrently then you need to learn rather a lot - see link. bahati nzuri kwako

I think it would be useful if you could explain exactly how your two files need to interact or how your app needs to function, that way we can provide a good solution for your case and not just a guess as to what you really need. Maybe provide a minimal example of your code/files/app?

sometimes all it takes is this, but it depends on your code/files/application...

The simple way to launch multiple threads is:
from threading import Thread
from file1 import func1
from file2 import func2

t1 = Thread(target=func1, args=(list, of, arguments))
t2 = Thread(target=func2, args=(list, of, arguments))

t1.start()
t2.start()

# here you can do something while threads are running

t1.join()
t2.join()

# here you can do something when both threads finished their job

I assume, that func1 from file1 is your job given in file1 and func2 from file2 is your job to be done from file2.
This code does not make this threads communicating with each other. If you want to do this I suggest you to dig a bit more in threading library.
